# PHP SoapCall help. Missing namespaces in parameters

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Im having some troubles with a SoapCall from PHP to an WSDL service.

My $client->_getLastRequest() function retrieve this XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:publicar>
        <aviso>
         //aviso content
        </aviso>
    </ns1:publicar>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

But I need to change it to :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:publicar>
        <ns1:aviso>
         //aviso content
        </ns1:aviso>
    </ns1:publicar>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I don´t understand how it´s the reason for the missing namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Both XML structures might be equivalent, depending on the XML metadata that is sent. What does the `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>` element contain?

Do you KNOW you have to change the namespace, or do you THINK you have to change it?